# Polynomial approximation on (0,1)

Tags: polynomials

Consider a polynomial in $x$
$$
x\mapsto\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}x^{n}.
$$
Suppose the root of this polynomial is in $\left(0,1\right)$. Suppose
further that we approximate the root of this polynomial by $\tilde{y}$,
attained by dropping high order terms:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{M}a_{n}\tilde{y}^{n}=0\text{ where }M<N.
$$
Then, letting the exact root be $y$, we have
$$
0=\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}y^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{M}a_{n}\tilde{y}^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{M}a_{n}\left(y^{n}-\tilde{y}^{n}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(y^{M+1}\right).
$$
Can the error $\left|y-\tilde{y}\right|$ be bounded in some meaningful
way?

Comment: Are you saying the polynomial has exactly one root in $(0,1)$? The issues is that if you call this root $y$, then it doesn't make sense to say you're approximating with $\tilde{y}$ from the lower order sum because the lower order sum could have a bunch of roots in $(0,1)$, so which is your approximation? In other words, how are you discerning which $\tilde{y}$ you want?